# How to get a phone number from an intent in an Android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I made an app which is set as dialer. I'm not sure how to get the number of the person someone clicked on from outside my app (for example a link in the browser of a number which opens the dialer) and chose my app as the dialer.

The intent filter I used:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I used to `getIntent` method to get the intent itself but I'm not sure when should I call to `getData` and when to `getExtras` since its not an intent I created myself and in this specific case not sure how to get the number out of the intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getData()` to extract a URI of the form `tel:XXXXX`, that's your phone number.

> Input: If nothing, an empty dialer is started; else getData() is URI of a phone number to be dialed or a tel: URI of an explicit phone number.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use documented function getNumberFromIntent (more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#getNumberFromIntent(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.Context))

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

```
 <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:autoLink="phone"
android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

This method really works

Comment: This method does not answer the question at all. You just posted some random snippet. To improve your answers, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).